# Access to Azure with SAML and Salesforce

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, salesforce, single-sign-on, saml

I configure on Azure AD (my IDP) the Salesforce Sandbox Application (my SP).
I setup all following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/salesforce-tutorial

But when i try to connect using SSO i have this error:

> AADSTS650056: Misconfigured application. This could be due to one of the following: the client has not listed any permissions for 'AAD Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Or, the admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, check the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the configured client application identifier. Or, check the certificate in the request to ensure it's valid.

I try to add inside API permissions the permission to AAD Graph but not work...

[image: permission]

UPDATE:

Now the error is:

> AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'URL SALESFORCE' was not
> found in the directory '29ab2178-e8d4-4b83-a2ef-f62ea37a6413'.  This
> can happen if the application has not been installed by the
> administrator  of the tenant or consented to by any user in the
> tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong
> tenant.

I need help please..

Thanks

Comment: You can follow the doc method to troubleshoot:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts650056-misconfigured-app

Comment: i check the Issuer in Azure and in Salesforce and is the same..is not the problem..

Comment: i just update the error

Comment: The documentation you're pointing at uses `Enterprise app` with SAML SSO but here you've configured an app registration ?

Comment: Check your `client id` to make sure it is correct.

Comment: @CarlZhao  i'm not very expert on Azure..but if i go on App registrations i have my Salesforce SP app.. but i'm not understand what i should check or modify...

Comment: @Thomas i see the app that i configure on Enterprise App in app registration

Comment: how are you testing the integration ? it should be saml protocol not oauth

Comment: @Thomas yes with SAML.. i configure SAML in Azure and then in Salesforce..

Comment: i have update the error with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. It was a wrong URL because for the Sandbox org i must put URL in that for:

https://domain.my.salesforce.com